# Multiple UDP ports for different SVC layers in native WebRTC and getting rid off Marker Bit

Tags: stream, udp, port, webrtc, svc

First of all, I need to find a way and develop/modify source code of WebRTC (native) in order to send SVC layers (for instance, 3 spatial layers) from different UDP ports to the receiver. Therefore, I need to have 3 different UDP streams going from the source to destination. What should I do in order to allocate 3 different UDP ports for 1 p2p session in native WebRTC code? Specific class and function names would be perfect.

Secondly, for decoding these different streams together at the receiver side, I need to get rid off Marker Bit and develop some kind of buffer that passes a decodable frame to decoder then renderer. Some suggestions would be very good.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: I did not understand what you meant. Having multiple streams for different layers, that is obvious.

Comment: do you have any idea for implementation strategy? @Ajay